# Help me save Christmas - clock and word puzzle

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, seasonal, puzzle-identification

[image]

My friend created this puzzle, it tells the Grinch's plan to ruin Christmas. I need to derive the plan from the clocks

I have counted that there are 60 words. The clue is that time doesn't go backwards, it's 24 hours and the word 'By' sits on the 00.00 minute hand.

I'm still not getting how to get the actual plan from this, as the words I get don't make sense. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Is your friend giving you marks for solving it?  ("3 marks" in the bottom right)
If this is part of an ongoing test or competition, it doesn't belong on Puzzling.  Questions from contests that have already concluded are fine, as long as you have permission to post them.